# XSL-FO and XML: Bibel Bookname in Header on every Page

Tags: xml, xslt, header, xsl-fo

I'm having trouble with XSL-FO and XML. I am actually quite new to this area. But I already love it as far as I can understand.

My problem is this, and I've tried everything so far:
I want the current Bible book name to appear in the header of every page until a new one starts.

I have the XSL and XML code here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/17

Are there possibilities? What do I have to change in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `fo:marker` and `fo:retrieve-marker` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker).

A copy of the book name would go in the `fo:marker` at the start of the first FO for the book, and the `fo:static-content` for the header would include an `fo:retrieve-marker` with a `retrieve-class-name` that matches the `marker-class-name` of the `fo:marker` that you added.

A search for questions about `fo:marker` will get you some examples of what to do.

---

I have fiddled with it at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDi/21

I added an `fo:marker` in the template for `CAPTION` (some properties omitted for clarity):

```
<xsl:template match="CAPTION">
  <fo:block page-break-before="always">
    <fo:marker marker-class-name="caption">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:marker>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

and replaced the "HEADER" text with an `fo:retrieve-marker` (some properties omitted for clarity):

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="kopf">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="caption" />
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

The connection between the two is the marker class name of "caption".

You don't seem to need them, but you can set the `retrieve-position` and `retrieve-boundary` properties on `fo:retrieve-marker` to control what happens when, for example, there's two `fo:marker` on the same page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i have no idea, how to do it. 

I've tried it and I'm a little confused because it doesn't work. I think that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have added more explanation. I hope that helps.

Comment: WOW! Thank your so much! This is working! Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it's working for you.